# python - how to cut/move a line from text file to input text box in html?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, selenium-webdriver, cut

So i have this text file, it contains like this

```
dog
husky
dog
siberian
```

and the html text input is this

```
<textarea id="name" class="name-input" style="width:350px" name="name"></textarea>
<textarea id="type" class="type-input" style="width:350px" name="type"></textarea>
```

so i want to move/cut the line from the text (dog to name-input and husky to type-input), i want to move it 2 lines at a time, then when the input is over, it will move/cut the next line(dog and siberian)

this is my selenium code for text input

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = ''
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

item = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'name')
item.click()
item.send_keys('')

item = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'type')
item.click()
item.send_keys('')
```

this my example of move line from text file, but this code move all lines not specific line

```
file1 = "E:/youtube.txt"
file2 = "E:/output.txt"

x = 6

with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
    data = f1.readlines()
with open(file1, 'w') as f1:
    for line in data[x:]:
        f1.write(line)
with open(file2, 'w') as f2:
    for line in data[:x]:
        f2.write(line)
```

I still dont know how to move/cut specific line

okay let me clarify what i need to do to solve the problem

i have only 1 text file (those code above is just an example for moving lines from text file to another text file)

1. i want to move/cut line from youtube.txt to html input textarea
2. when those 2 input textarea have been inputed(cut/move line 1 and 2), then i want the next line (line 3 and 4, etc) inputed again to those 2 input textarea
3. so it would be automatically inputed until the last line from the text file is end

Comment: i edited with some coding i have worked out so far, i really need help, thats the last piece i needed

Comment: You are showing two text files, "youtube.txt" and "output.txt". I'm assuming that the "dog", etc. values are in "youtube.txt"? Please clarify your question

Comment: I recommend that you describe in words the steps that you need to take to solve the problem. For example, it might be something like 1. Read a word from the text file. 2. Enter the data in the input field. See if you can figure out how to translate these two steps into code for one of the input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use a `for` to loop through the lines of text in `data`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

file1 = "E:/youtube.txt"
file2 = "E:/output.txt"
url = ''
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
    data = f1.readlines()

for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'name').send_keys(data[i].strip())
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'type').send_keys(data[i+1].strip())
    # do whatever else before inputting new values
```

Comment: i think this one could answer my question, but what if there's more than 2 lines in the file?

Comment: You didn't describe what you wanted to happen to anything past the first two lines. That's what the comment at the end of the script is talking about. The for loop will loop through all the lines, in pairs. Just replace the `driver.find...` lines with a `print()` of the `send_keys()` data and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

```
name_items = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, 'name')
type_items = driver.find_elements(By.NAME, 'type')
for name in name_items:
    index = name_items.index(name)
    type = type_items[index]
    with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
         csv.writer(f).writerow([name, type])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).